# Delete one of two links to a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Through various manipulations the user may wind up with two or more links to the same table such as links to x, x1, x2 and so forth.

I would like to delete those extraneous links (x1...) as a matter of clean-up even though they do no real harm sitting there.

I have tried

```html
   Sub KillDBFile(FN As String)    ' Doesn't word to delete link
   Dim x As Byte
Dim s, t, u As String
Dim dbOther As Database
Set dbOther = OpenDatabase(DataFileAndPath)
For x = 1 To 5
    t = Str(x) ' for debug/test only
    u = Mid(Str(x), 2)
    s = FN & Mid(Str(x), 2)
    On Error Resume Next
    dbOther.TableDefs.Delete s
Next
dbOther.Close
End Sub
```

where DataFileAndPath is the path and file to the linked table ( i.e. "C:.....\") and FN is the table name. I inserted the s,t and u variables to aid in debugging. I find this does not delete the links as desired

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide an example of link that you watt to delete?

Comment: I've been trying to find a way to submit a screenshot of the table listing without success. Finally put iit up on one of my sites: http://rgcle.com/TwoLinksl.gif

Comment: See http://rgcle.com/TwoLinksl.gif. Is that what you want?

Comment: Is your intention to run code which looks at linked tables in another database (*DataFileAndPath*) and removes the duplicate links within that other database?

Comment: No - in my front end I have two (or more) links to the same table in the back end, The additional links are worthless so I'd like to run code (while initializing the front end) to get rid of these extraneous links.

Comment: OK.  I think this would be simpler with a table of "approved links".  So *PersonEventRecord* would be one entry in that table.  Then you examine each link, and delete any (such as *PersonEventRecord1*) which are not present in that table.  Would that suit?

Comment: Sound reasonable, but my biggest issue is how to delete the link without deleting the table. A small hunk of code would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Deleting a link never deletes the table to which that link points.  If you need a code example to delete a link, here is one method: `CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "PersonEventRecord1"`

Comment: That is just what I needed. To get rid of some trash that could be left over by some user action.